# Were Samson's parents with him when he tore the lion?

Tags: judges

In Judges 14:5-6 it says Samson went with his parents to Timnah, then it says as **they** approached the vineyards a lion approached Samson but then it says Samson did not tell his parents what he had done, implying that his parents weren't there, but the texts says they went together, isn't it a contradiction?

> **Judges 14:5-6** Samson went down to Timnah together with his father and mother. As they approached the vineyards of Timnah, suddenly a young lion came roaring toward him. 6 The Spirit of the Lord came powerfully upon him so that he tore the lion apart with his bare hands as he might have torn a young goat. But he told neither his father nor his mother what he had done.

Comment: How could Samson have done that?  When the lion opened it’s mouth to bite Samson he grabbed the inside of the jaws with his two hands and tore off the bottom jaw from the skull. That was how they skinned a dead young goat. Tearing the skin off the body over the head and down to the tail. (I think))

Comment: LOL, maybe Samson & his parents were traveling in wagon/cart/chariot that have a roof & curtains, and were pulled by an ox, bull or horse, etc., and Samson may have been in the driver seat while his parents were within the part of the wagon veiled by the curtains so they could Not see outside. Therefore, Samson could kill the lion while they could Not see because they were behind the curtain. Or maybe it was night time, and the parents were sleeping in back of the cart when Samson killed the lion LOL. just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

The very fact that Samson did not tell his parents (Judges 14:6) what he had done suggests that they were not with Samson when this was done.  Perhaps it was done out of their sight while they were travelling.

The above is confirmed in V9 where the parents remained ignorant of the incident.

Matthew Poole suggests this:

> He told not his father or his mother, lest by their means it should be
> publicly known; for he wisely considered that it was not yet a fit
> time to awaken the jealousies and fears of the Philistines concerning
> him, as this would have done.

Comment: LOL, maybe Samson & his parents were traveling in wagon/cart/chariot that have a roof & curtains, and were pulled by an ox, bull or horse, etc., and Samson may have been in the driver seat while his parents were within the part of the wagon veiled by the curtains so they could Not see outside. Therefore, Samson could kill the lion while they could Not see because they were behind the curtain. Or maybe it was night time, and the parents were sleeping in back of the cart when Samson killed the lion LOL. just a guess.